# How to loop through every row, calculate difference and then average everything?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a model called Client that has these info :

```
private Long int;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)        
private List<Results> results;
```

and The model Results has these info :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name='client_id') 
private Client client;
@OneToOne
private Scores score;
private Date submittedDate;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this :

For every user get the score of their first result and the score of their last result, find the difference. 
And then average out everyone's differences.
How do I write this function that calculates it?

The Client returns a list of all results, and then for 
   difference : results[last] - results[0]
   and then a loop :

```
for (int i=0; i <= client.count(); i++)
    difference = results[last] - results[0];
    sum += difference;
    average = sum/client.count();`
```

I just have difficulty into turning this into code that works in Spring.
Do I write this in the ClientServiceImplementation and then have the queries in ClientRepository ?
Any help is appreciated!!!

the Score class has :

```
  private Long id;
  private Double score;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Client> clients = clientRepository.findAll();

Double meanDiff = clients.stream()
    .map(client -> {
        List<Result> results = client.getResults();
        if (results.size() >= 2) {
            Score first = results.get(0);
            Score last = results.get(results.size() - 1);
            return last.value - first.value;
        } else {
           return 0.0;
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(it -> it));
```

Note: you did not specify what is the `Score` class, so I assumed it has a `value` field of type `Double`.

Update: this is another example but ignoring clients with `numberOfResults < 2`:

```
Double meanDiff = clients.stream()
    .map(client -> client.getResults())
    .filter(results -> results.size() >= 2) // <-- keep these only
    .map(results -> {
        Score first = results.get(0);
        Score last = results.get(results.size() - 1);
        return last.value - first.value;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(it -> it));
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This returns a results. but if I may ask,
for example if I have 6 Clients, out of which only 3 have more than 2 Results.
the Collectors.averagingDouble, does it calculate the average of all scoresDiff divided by 6Clients ?

Comment: @MonnIca yes, this includes clients that have fewer than 2 results. If you want to ignore them, use the `filter` operator. I updated the answer with another example where they are ignored.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you soo sooo much !!